# Xamarin.Forms Imagesource issue

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, uwp, imagesource

I have a view with an image: `<Image Source="{Binding MainUrl}"/>`

Image binding value : [My image source on loading from database](https://db3pap007files.storage.live.com/y4mwjIiSJNQyHu_ygK5ARex8ptB5t5vpKAd3xmJatmFOiUHMZab3UFlHPnZMmMQoIK6q04ILVcVsoBY0jQTG1OSFmG92jD_hzBYfeQlvUxWR-Ju1z3q3Y0pLJxLplRVmy4NQApVgGYyduM_Pci0CqSTEcBW7vskviXQunFSAWxQquo5yZiGZzRZUNLL4gh397tv?width=762&height=90&cropmode=none)

the value of MainUrl variable is stored in an sqlite table.`public string LogoUrl { get; set; }`
viewmodel :

```
private string _logoUrl;
public string LogoUrl
        {
            get { return _logoUrl; }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ref _logoUrl, value);
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LogoUrl));

            }
        }
```

the user has the option to change the image using filepicker :

```
            var file = await FilePicker.PickAsync(options);
            if (file == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
            MainUrl = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
            LblImportLogo = file.FullPath;
            Parameter.LogoUrl = file.FullPath;
```

when I choose an image with filepicker, this one is well displayed and the the path is saved into sqlite table but when I restart the application, the image is no longer displayed despite the path being well informed (this one is external). the problem is in all platforms, UWP,android and IOS. can you help me find a solution.

**Mainpage.xaml.cs :**

```
public MainPage()
        {
            var parameterStore = new SQLiteParameterStore(DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDb>());
            var pageService = new PageService();

            ViewModel = new MainPageViewModel(parameterStore, pageService);
            
            InitializeComponent();

            NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            ViewModel.LoadDataCommand.Execute(null);
            base.OnAppearing();
        }


        public MainPageViewModel ViewModel
        {
            get { return BindingContext as MainPageViewModel; }
            set { BindingContext = value; }
        }
```

**MainPageViewModel :**

```
......

private ImageSource _mainurl;
        public ImageSource MainUrl
        {
            get { return _mainurl; }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ref _mainurl, value);
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MainUrl));
            }
        }
......

private async Task LoadData()
         {
             

             var parameters = await _parameterStore.GetAll();

             var elts = parameters.Count();             
             if (elts < 1)
             {

                //set default values
                mainParameter = new Parameter();             
                mainParameter.LogoUrl = "default.jpg";
                MainUrl = mainParameter.LogoUrl;

            }
             else
             {
                //set parameters
                 mainParameter = parameters[0];                 

                MainUrl = ImageSource.FromFile(mainParameter.LogoUrl);             

            }    
        }
```

Comment: you are binding to `MainUrl` but the code you posted is for a property named `LogoUrl`

Comment: if the problem occurs on startup, it would be helpful to show the code that loads the image at startup

Comment: i added more information. thank you for your replay

Comment: does `MainPageViewModel` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?  Have you verified that `MainUrl` is getting set to the correct value when the page loads?

Comment: Yep, INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented in my baseviewmodel. and the value of MainUrl was stored with the new value.

Comment: It seems that MainUrl get the correct value. In you description, delete comma in Image Binding.  And check the sqlite database if you saved the data correctly.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT, i'am sorry for the comma( copy error). the binding is correct and the value in the database also, the first display is correct. The problem is when i close the app and reopen it  the load data brig the path (of the new image ) saved in the database but there is an issue to display this image. So i start coding xamarin, is there an extra coding to reload the image from filepath? imagesource.fromfile(path) is not enough?

Comment: Could you share the path for me? When you load the file with path directly, does it show?

Comment: sure,  i edit my post

Comment: The path you used is a invalid image path for Android device. You need to check it again.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT, The execution image that i show you it was on windows (UWP). what do you mean by check it again?

Comment: Did the image not show in uwp?

Comment: the first display when i pick a new image, it shows in uwp then i store the path in my sqlite table  then i bind the new path from sqlite to the view (on loading). the second way does not show the image. When i took the path directly to the imagesource.fromfile(pathstoredindatabase)

Comment: If you use the path directly, it still not show the image? It seems you binding a  Url for the image. Why do you use the magesource.fromfile? Have you try to load the Url?